# How can I read a text file with binary values, where each row is a binary vector itself using Numpy?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

The idea is that the text file has 150 rows where each row is a string of 1024 bits (a representation of a 32x32 image).

What i want to achieve is to have an array of 150 elements where every element is an array of size 1024.

By trying the code below i get an array of 150 elements with inf value. 
Is there a way to convert those values to vectors using numpy's loadtxt directly.

Thank you in advance!

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("digits.txt")
```

Comment: Do the lines in the text file consist of the ASCII characters `0` and `1`?   If not, how are the binary vectors represented in the file?

Comment: It actually seems a bit strange to store binary data in a text file. Why not directly call it a binary file? You could just use `.read(128)` for each 1024 bits... no newlines ("rows") needed.

Comment: Did you read the `loadtxt` docs?  Default dtype is float.  If you have a 1000 digits without delimiter, it tries to make one number from that.  The `inf` value is likely.

Answer (score 1):

If each line is exactly the same length and contains only the characters `0` and `1`, you can use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), with `delimiter=1`.  When the argument `delimiter` is a single integer, `genfromtxt` treats each line as a sequence of fixed-width fields.  The value given to `delimiter` specifies the field width.

For example, suppose the file `01.txt` contains

```
0001
1010
1111
0000
1001
```

Here's how you can use `genfromtxt` to read that into a NumPy integer array with shape (5, 4):

```
In [2]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                

In [3]: data = np.genfromtxt('01.txt', delimiter=1, dtype=np.int8)                                                                                        

In [4]: data                                                                                                                                              
Out[4]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

Answer (score 0):

supposed your text file contains 128 characters in each line (excluding newline character), each character representing 1 byte / 8 bits, you could use

```py
data = np.loadtxt(file, dtype=np.str)
bits_arr = []
for line in data:
    byte_arr = np.frombuffer(line.encode('UTF-8'), dtype=np.uint8) # UTF-8 assumed
    bits_arr.append(np.unpackbits(byte_arr).reshape(32,32))
```

`bits_arr` will then contain 1 "32x32 bitmap" for each line. Note that `reshape(32,32)` will fail if an invalid number of bytes (!=128) is read in a line.

Sidenote: it is probably more efficient here to use a simple `readlines()` instead of carrying around all the overhead of `np.loadtxt` since you actually don't use what this function can do for you. The code could therefore be simplified to

```py
bits_arr = []
with open(file, 'rb') as binfile:
    line = binfile.readline().strip() # strip to remove newline char
    byte_arr = np.frombuffer(line, dtype=np.uint8)
    bits_arr.append(np.unpackbits(byte_arr).reshape(32,32))
```